# application:openUrl: is called multiple times in iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, uiapplicationdelegate, openurl

For this problem, I created a new project with a single view.

I set a url scheme and added a label in the view.

And code is here.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    ViewController *vc = (ViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    vc.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",vc.textLabel.text,url.absoluteString];
    return YES;
}
```

It works fine.

But if I add some time-consuming operations at app initialize,
like this.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    return YES;
}
```

Then I found this problem through those steps:

1. use safari to start the app through input the url scheme
2. wait it jumps to the app, and press the home button immediately
3. tap the app icon to continue
4. get two lines of url on the label

## UIApplication calls application:openUrl: multiple times.

I tried using this delegate, same problem.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
```

You can press the home button and tap the app icon multiple times, than openUrl will be called multiple times, it depends on cost of time-consuming operations.

I tested on iOS 9.3.3 and iOS 9.3.1, got same problem.

I tried on iOS 8.1.2 and iOS 10.2 not found this problem.

Any ideas/suggestions would be highly helpful & very thankful

Comment: Why do you complicate things, if you get two lines, that means you don't do any checks on what sets on what, just do a simple check and make sure you don't get values twice no matter how many times it gets called? If you only find this bug in 9.3.3 and 9.3.1 , that will solve your problems also makes your app future proof , and gives you control over what happens in your code as you expect it too. What do you think?

Comment: @Sneak This delegate can be called multiple times. If you use the same url scheme, you will get same url string. But I only use the scheme once, it will call this delegate twice or more. I can not distinguish.

Comment: I have removed the duplicate flag,  even tho I suspect this being a bug if you only can produce it in 2 versions mentioned. As I mentioned, you can simply create a Boolean property and make sure you only allow the url scheme fired once in the delegate method and handle things manually to avoid firing off **your methods** multiple times. Not sure If I understand you correctly. However,if that doesnt help, GL!